# How to place DropDownList1_selectedIndexChanged event in JSON.Parse()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
        function initialize() {

        var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString()%>');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };
```

Please help me..how to place that event in JSON.Parse method..I already create "ConvertDataTableString()..but i want to change the location in dropdown list..for that i placed dropdown list..please say any one....please

Comment: How you are populating drop down list from java script or from server side?

Comment: i am tried to displaying the selected location,using dropdown list

Comment: public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.15.20;Initial Catalog=KJLMAY;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=newdb_2010"))
        {

Comment: using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title=city,lat=Lattitude,lng=Longtude,Description from LocationDetails", con))
            {

Comment: create web service and call your function on jquery event change function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

  $('select').click(function () {        
    // Do your code here   
  });       

});
```